# clearTimeout setInterval not working. But does in other script?

Tags: timer, setinterval, cleartimeout

I wish for this animation to loop over and over throughout the page duration, But for some reason the clearTimer is not fulfilling the job. or i have got the looping wrong thinking that clearing the timers would produce a loop as the function is granted.

```
<script>
(function () {
var a1;
a1 = setTimeout(anim1,9000);

var a2;
a2 = setTimeout(anim2,10000);

var a3;
a3 = setTimeout(anim3,11000);

var a4;
a4 = setTimeout(anim4,12000);

function anim1() {
document.getElementById("tx1").animate([
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"},
  { transform: "translateY(-10px)"}, 
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"}
], {
  duration: 1000,
})
}

function anim2() {
document.getElementById("tx2").animate([
{ transform: "translateY(0px)"},
  { transform: "translateY(-10px)"}, 
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"}
], {
  duration: 1000,
})
}

function anim3() {
document.getElementById("tx3").animate([
 { transform: "translateY(0px)"},
  { transform: "translateY(-10px)"}, 
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"}
], {
  duration: 1000,
})
}

function anim4 () {
clearTimeout(a1);
clearTimeout(a2);
clearTimeout(a3);
clearTimeout(a4);

}
})();


</script>
```

I can see no problems, and the same script runs in another file...

I just want the animation to loop over basically. but it runs once, then dies, i assume that the cleartimeout is not the problem. ???

Comment: Can you explain what you think the anim4 function is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Found a Workaround Allthough im still not sure if im clearing the timers correctly. But its done the job so must be ok now... Thanks for your help folks...

heres the script..

```
<script>


window.onload=function start() {
var a1 = setTimeout(anim1,9000);

var a2 = setTimeout(anim2,10000);

var a3 = setTimeout(anim3,11000);

var a4 = setTimeout(anim4,12000);

function anim1() {
document.getElementById("tx1").animate([
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"},
  { transform: "translateY(-10px)"}, 
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"}
], {
  duration: 1000,
})

}

function anim2() {


document.getElementById("tx2").animate([
{ transform: "translateY(0px)"},
  { transform: "translateY(-10px)"}, 
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"}
], {
  duration: 1000,
})

}

function anim3() {
document.getElementById("tx3").animate([
 { transform: "translateY(0px)"},
  { transform: "translateY(-10px)"}, 
  { transform: "translateY(0px)"}
], {
  duration: 1000,
})

}

function anim4() {
clearTimeout("a3")
clearTimeout("a1");
clearTimeout("a2");
clearTimeout("a4");
start();
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: I was also not providing the necessary syntax I.E --> " "  - may have had something to do with it in the 1st place...

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the value returned from setTimeout to clearTimeout function.
In your case, it should be clearTimeout(a1) instead of clearTimeout(anim1) and so on.